# Organizing Selenium tests in Eclipse for batch execution

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automated-tests

This is an organizational question - 
I have a set of "Java Projects" within the same workspace in Eclipse, comprising of a series of Selenium tests (pretty much each it's own Java Project). They are all within a same package. Now, in an effort towards automated execution, I need to batch execute these.
Any ideas on how to better organize the scripts to do this? Can I execute a series of scripts via Eclipse itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this by creating a singular "Java Project". In it, a single package, comprised of multiple classes - each representing a test case. A "Run Configuration" can be set via Eclipse that enables batch execution.
Now, onto some test failure recovery ... :)